# Error passing parsing JSON values using Ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

This is my Ajax call

```
<script>
$.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:3000/house/get-all",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data,    
        crossDomain: "true",      

      }
      });
</script>
```

This is my html code:

```
<div id="houses">
This is place to put content. You can put slider, short description about your website and place some links for navigation.
</p>
</div>
```

ERROR:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: @brk i dont understand what you say..

Comment: you have `dataType: 'json', data,`, where are you defining `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `data,` if you are not passing any data in your ajax options:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:3000/house/get-all",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    // data, -- remove this or pass something here
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!